# move mailbox from exchange 2010 back to 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

i need to move a user back to 2003 so our blackberry server software will send them mail on their phone.  I attempted to just move them back but i'm getting an error of "couldn't find system mailbox 'SystemMailbox{GUID}' in active directory".  Any thoughts?

Comment: Upgrade your BES server so it can connect to Exchange 2010?

Comment: I have some people that cannot be moved to 2010 yet that still use the BES server.  Unfortunately I can't connect it to 2010 until all my people are moved over and this one user also needs BES.  The server also can't connect to two exchange servers at the same time.  I thought about installing a trial of the newest BES on another server and attaching that one to 2010, but I don't know how long these other people will still be on 2003.  I want to exhaust my other options first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out blackberry is no longer used by the organization and to solve the exchange issues, we moved to Google Workspace.  Best decision ever.